# Is a protection diode needed for a resistive load?

Tags: switches, resistive-load

In some applications a flyback diode is added parallel to the load. Is that because the switching causes reverse voltage for inductive loads? What if we have a resistive load instead? Do we still need to take care of switching? In the below figure there is a read switch operating on an inductive load. Would we still need it if the load were nothing but a resistor?
[image]

Comment: There is always parasitic inductance.

Comment: Can you really make a load that's just a resistor? What about the wires connecting the resistor to the switch? They look awfully like a single-turn inductor to me...

Comment: the question is would it be negligible?

Comment: @MattYoung: There's also always parasitic capacitance. Combinations of parasitic inductance and capacitance will cause ringing when a circuit disconnects.  If inductance dominates, the peak voltage amplitude on open may be very high; if capacitance dominates, the peak current on close may be very high.  If neither dominates, voltage and current will stay within reasonable bounds even in the absence of protection.

Comment: If you can control your environment so that the transients at switch turnoff cause acceptably low damage and other problems then the diode *can* be omitted. If you wish to control your situation so that "how did that happen" unexpected factors in your environment do not generate transients at switch turnoff that cause unacceptable damage and other problems then adding a diode - usually very compact and low cost compared to other circuit elements, is usually a very very good idea. In a design that mattered I'd use one "as of right" unless there were compelling reasons not to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the load is a resistor you should be safe without a diode. Resistors have a parasitic inductance of some sort but the inductance value is usualy very, very small unless you are dealing with high power wire wound resistors that usually have a (somewhat) high parasitic inductance.

Have a look [here](http://www.resistorguide.com/inductance/) too.

So the answer is no, you won't need it in almost all practical cases.

Answer (score 3):

I know this has been answered already but thought I'd throw this in there as well--

You only need a diode on inductive loads, such as a transformer or a motor. This is because when the magnetic field collapses, it causes back-EMF that can damage your circuitry. The diode provides a safe path so that the EMF can dissipate without causing damage, but will only conduct when back-EMF is present.

Purely resistive loads do not generate any back-EMF, though in reality every load has some inductance and capacitance as well as resistance. However, for all intents and purposes it is generally safe to leave out the protection diode unless you have a significant inductance for the load.

Answer (score 1):

> In some applications a flyback diode is added parallel to the ...
>   inductive load.  ... 
>   Would we still need it if the load were nothing but a resistor?

If you can control your environment so that the transients at switch turnoff cause acceptably low damage and other problems then the diode *can* be omitted.

If you wish to control your situation so that "how did that happen?" unexpected factors in your environment do not generate transients at switch turnoff that cause unacceptable damage and other problems then adding a diode  is usually a very very good idea.

A suitably rated diode is usually very compact and low cost compared to other circuit elements involved. 
In a design 'that mattered' I'd tend to use a diode "as of right" unless there were compelling reasons not to. A compelling reason may eg be guaranteed pure resistive load adjacent to switch (e not flexible wiring connected), no other connections, no risk of relevant long term contamination or degradation occurring, or (getting a bit keen now) conducted or radiated effects adding energy to the circuit, and cost is critical and room limited and diode failure probability higher than problem probability, ... .

Such "overkill" usually has minimal overall cost. When "underkill" happens unexpectedly in real world volume designs the cost is often far in excess of anticipating it. You cannot and should not protect against every hypothetical problem. But if the chances of protection being needed is only "very low" and the cost of needing but not having it is 'very very very high" then there will be a point where it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, at least in an industrial environment, the only time shunt diodes are necessary is when a relay coil is being driven by a Solid State component. Diodes are there to prevent spikes created by the collapsing field on the relay coil when it is switched off. I cant for the life of me see any reason to protect a resistive load.

Well maybe, if its hooked to a very high impedance solid state output, a.k.a. A CMOS driver driving through a low resistance. But generally new CMOS outputs have protection diodes internally. In the old days of CMOS merely handling the chips without grounding the arm you pick it up with could damage the chips outputs (and inputs) from static electricity.